# ModuleNotFound error despite it being installed?

Tags: python, pip

when I run `import matplotlib as mpl` I get an error saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'"

I have tried running `pip install matplotlib` and it tells me I've already installed it (which I know is true) and yet I still get the same error.

my code used to run perfectly fine but now I just get that error. thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Check if `pip` is related to the same Python `--version` and maybe virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You complain that this sequence of commands fails:

```bash
$ pip install matplotlib
$ python -c 'import matplotlib'
```

Apparently `pip` is not using the same
[conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) environment or
[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
that `python` is.
Use `$ which pip`, `$ which python`,
and `$ python -m site` to diagnose that.

To fix, invoke pip as:

```bash
$ python -m pip install matplotlib
$ python -c 'import matplotlib'
```

Running the pip module in that way will ensure consistency
between the install and the use.

---

Recommend you delete that `pip` command,
as it's not doing you any favors.
Or fix your PATH order so typing "pip" and typing "python"
at the command prompt will run the program you *actually* want to run.